# Flutter: Navigation in a pop-up dialog

Tags: flutter, navigation, dependencies, flutter-dependencies, flutter-desktop

Is it possible to use a separate Navigator in a pop up window? Separate BuildContext?

I have a working app (APP1) and I would like to show it in a new one (APP2) (e.g. on a button press to open the existing app). APP1 has multiple pages.

I was able add the APP1 as an dependency to APP2 and load the main page in a popup dialog (Alert dialog).

The issue happens when I try to navigate through the APP1. If I click on the button in the APP1 it changes the page in the whole new app.

I would like to have separate navigation in the pop up dialog, so that the included app Navigator works only in the pop-up dialog.

What would be a preferred/possible way to achieve this?

**Here is a small example:**
[Soure code](https://www.mediafire.com/file/7dqni5cixzpfu73/example.7z/file)

The example consists of 2 apps (APP1 and APP2). APP2 includes APP1 and shows it in a pop up dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a nested Navigator (if you're using Navigator 1.0 in Flutter) by adding the **Navigator** widget inside your dialog component, that way you manage the navigation of pages within that dialog itself, create nested routes and navigate only within that navigation stack.

You can do something like:

```dart
class NestedDialog extends StatelessWidget {
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       body: Navigator(
          key: <ADD_UNIQUE_KEY>, // add a unique key to refer to this navigator programmatically
          initialRoute: '/',
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
              // here you return your own page widgets wrapped
              // inside a PageRouteBuilder
          }
       )
     );
   }
}
```

Then you can even use **Flutter**'s own **showDialog** and load your custom dialog widget like so:

```dart
showDialog(context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      builder: (BuildContext cxt) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: NestedDialog()
      );
    });
```

Something along those lines. Give that a shot. Here's a Github Gist you can run on DartPad.dev so you can see what I mean. You don't have to create two apps; just distribute your app into two main widgets, and the child pages go under each main widget's child pages; See gist https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/d769e6e766fbacb2f5c166dd3bceab51. Run it on DartPad.dev.

Comment: Hi Roman. I just added a small example which will better explain my issue. I've checked your answer, but I was not sure how to integrate it to my app.

Comment: Check the Github Gist I created with my example of how you don't need two apps, but a single app with two main widgets, each widget then can have subpages. The widget that shows inside the dialog can have its own Navigation stack. Check it out and if it works, let's edit the answer so we can mark it correct. https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/d769e6e766fbacb2f5c166dd3bceab51

Comment: Great answer! To save future me's the headache - if you're creating the global key inside this **StatelessWidget** be sure to make it static. Otherwise create a `StatefulWidget`

Comment: How do you pop the modal with this configuration? If using a navigator, Navigator.pop method just goes back a page in the navigator to a blank page and doesn't pop the modal itself.